# React native apk release issue

Tags: android, react-native

I am new in react-native. I created one app it was working fine on local but when i run the release APK the app crash on change screen/navigate to another screen.

I have tried for days now to resolve this without success. Im not really sure what is causing this issue as when i run the debug version the app works fine no issues.

As soon as i open the installed signed APK the app crashes.
I am using the below packages.

```
{  "name": "testAPP",  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.4",
    "react-native-auth0": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.9",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.1",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-simple-modal": "^9.0.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.16.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.16.7",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Use [Sentry][https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/] to find the cause of the error.

Comment: connect the mobile to pc , open android studio, and look at logcat. You will get the idea of the crash.